# What is the best way to handle 4 way relation between 2 models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have two models: **Company** and **User**

This is the situation:

- Company can follow another company
- User can follow a company
- User can follow another user

What is the best way to define the relationships and how will the join model look like?

Also, are there any best practises when addressing such situations?

**Update**

Sorry, to have not mentioned this earlier. I am aware of the various relationship types available. My question is **'which is the best fit'**?

Comment: I think you should go with polymorphic association(you can see in RailsCasts Episode#154)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to polymorphic associations, we can put all relations into one table which like this:

```
create_table :follows do |t|
        t.references :followable, :polymorphic => true
        t.references :followed_by, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Then the models are:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :following_objects, :class_name => 'Follow', :as => :followed_by
    has_many :followed_objects, :class_name => 'Follow', :as => :followable
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :following_objects, :class_name => 'Follow', :as => :followed_by
    has_many :followed_objects, :class_name => 'Follow', :as => :followable
end

class Follow < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :followable, :polymorphic => true
    belongs_to :followed_by, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Sorry for the ugly names.

Comment: I do not understand the terms 'following_objects' and 'followed_objects'. What is objects here?

Comment: following_objects: who does a user/company follow? and followed_objects: by whom is a user/company followed by? I cannot think of any proper names for them.

Comment: Sorry if I am asking something obvious. Shouldn't we define them as 'following_companies' and 'following_users' seperately?

Comment: As you said, a user can follow a company and/or another user. In polymorphic associations, we care about that a user is following something more than that a user is following some users or some companies. If you want, you can get which users/companies are followed by a user with some scopes.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your question I would suggest you to go through couple of Railscasts videos:

1. http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many
2. http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association

And this is described very well on RubyonRails website

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

I would say look these for your case:

1. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association
2. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I also think that - in this case - a polymorphic association is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

*A basic idea would be to use **two self-referencing** assocations:*

- User -> Friendship <- User
- Company -> Partnership <- Company

**models/user.rb**

```
has_many :friendships
has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
has_many :inverse_friendships, :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
has_many :inverse_friends, :through => :inverse_friendships, :source => :user
```

**models/friendship.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"
```

**models/company.rb**

```
has_many :partnerships
has_many :partners, :through => :partnerships
has_many :inverse_partnerships, :class_name => "Partnership", :foreign_key => "partner_id"
has_many :inverse_partners, :through => :inverse_partnerships, :source => :company
```

**models/partnership.rb**

```
belongs_to :company
belongs_to :partner, :class_name => "Company"
```

---

*And **one many-to-many** assocation:*

- User -> CompanyUser <- Company

**models/user.rb**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :companies
```

**models/company.rb**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

So for this implementation you will need 5 tables (users, friendships, companies, partnerships and companies_users) if you are using a RDBMS.

You can get a nice example in this screencast:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association

Comment: Is there no way where i can have one universal join model 'polymorphic'ly defined for each relation?

Comment: Yes you could, but from an implementation perspective it is a lot simpler to keep them separated... well thats just my personal preference...

Comment: This answer is quite non-idiomatic, given that rails supports polymorphic associations.

Comment: Rails and Active Record support many things, it doesn't mean that you have to use all of them... will you care about performance in the future? will you expect to have hundreds, thousands or millions of records?... are you going to pack everything in a single table?